# context.drawImage() not working on mobile even after .onLoad (TypeError: null is not an object)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

Really confused on this one... My code runs fine on desktop, but for some reason it will not run correctly on mobile browsers. I think it might be because the canvas isn't being created fast enough on mobile (that's what the error suggests to me, at least). Is there some way i can asynchronously do the .drawImage? Maybe something similar to the .onload but for the canvas itself?

"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'ctxtemp.drawImage')"

```
...
const tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctxtemp = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
tempCanvas.id = 'temp-canvas';
tempCanvas.width = 4096;
tempCanvas.height = 4096;
const mask = new Image();
mask.src = part.mask;
mask.onload = () => {
      ctxtemp.drawImage(mask, 0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);
...
```

Comment: The one operation that failed was `getContext("2d")`, so it throws at drawImage because it was really `null.drawImage()` that was being called. Now why getContext("2d") returns null... Do you have some extensions active?

Comment: I do not believe I am using any extensions, no. This function is being called about ten times in a row asynchronously, but that shouldn't cause any issues. It's weird because a number of the function calls work as expected and draw properly, but a few random times the context comes up null. And only on mobile.. on desktop everything works fine.

Comment: "This function is being called about ten times in a row asynchronously" and are you releasing the contexts and canvases afterward? A 4096*4096 2D context represents 67MB of raw pixel data and sometimes more since they may duplicate it for buffering. Browsers, mostly on low end devices will prevent your code from geenating too many canvas contexts.

Comment: Perhaps 4k is a bit ambitious.. thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little late to answer this, but I was experiencing this problem and yesterday I accidentally solved this.

The issue of `drawImage()` and other functions that make use of external files for correct operation seem to come up against a security issue in the Android system, but `I was able to understand this with the help of the Acode app.`
By editing my page in the app and running the file, it opens a "mini-HTML server" (**localhost:8158/"filename" URL**), also allowing linked JS and CSS scripts that were also not being read. To see your page working correctly, simply copy the URL that Acode generates to execute the file and paste this URL into your preferred browser, keeping Acode open. Everything works fine there.

This is my first post and I hope it is very useful for others who have researched this problem.